# Conditional probability: rains on $4^{th}$ day if $1^{st}$ day is a rainy day?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

{Probability of a day being a rainy day only depends on the day before}. If yesterday was a rainy day then there is $0.6$ percent chance that today will be a rainy day and if yesterday was a sunny day probability of today being a rainy day is $0.4$.
Then what is the probability that the $4^{th}$ day is a rainy day if the $1^{st}$ day was a rainy day?
This is my first question in this site please forgive me for making mistakes in the format of writing question.

Comment: Sum the 4 cases. RRRR + RSRR + RRSR + RSSR

Comment: Using capitals doesn´t make a good impression. It looks horrible for me. Please make an edit.

Comment: @Nilknarf I tried two methods one is what wavex did in the answer other is i tried solving that the fourth day only depends on the third day.

Answer (score 1):

*Using WW1's method*

RRRR + RSRR + RRSR + RSSR

$$(1)(.6)(.6)(.6) + (1)(.4)(.4)(.6) + (1)(.6)(.4)(.4) + (1)(.4)(.6)(.4)= 0.504$$

Assuming the only weather types are sunny and rainy